# ANTLR and Xtext integration for developing plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, antlr, xtext, stringtemplate

My current project is focusing on code generation from High-level specification. More specifically, developers write high-level specifications and compiler parses them and generates Java code. For parser, I have used ANTLR grammar and for code generation I have used StringTemplateFiles.

For providing nice editor support (with syntax high lighting & coloring), I have used xText.

Now, the real problem comes - how can I integrate xText editor support with ANTLR parser and code generator? I want to provide nice eclipse plugin to developers.

Should I stick with xText and try to solve integration problem?/ Should I use only ANTLR and StringTemplateFiles and try to create Eclipse plugin out of it (I do not know - how can I do this)?

Other alternative suggestions are also welcomed.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xtext generates Antlr parser and support template based generation via xtend in addition to the eclipse plugin - why not use it exclusively?

Comment: Thanks for the reply !  xText is nice tool for template based generation. However, the current templates are written in StringTemplate. My project manager does not want to change it to xtend template.

Comment: you can also drive your templates from the xtext triggers (in Java or Xtend) - you need to use the same Juice injection you'd use for the xtend generators

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use xtend to write the code generator. the only thing you have to cope with is the interface `IGenerator` it should be possible to call StringTemplate from there (Implementing the call in Java or Xtend)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am bit new to xtext. Could you please give an example for more clarity.